# How can I award users XP for being in a voice channel?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am relatively new to node.js and discord.js.

I am trying to give each user in a specific voice channel a random amount of XP using discord-xp npm, for every 30 seconds they spend in the voice channel.

I am encountering this error

```
/home/runner/Peeper-Bash/index.js:78
    const randomXP = await Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
                     ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
```

This is my code

```
setInterval(() =>{ 
let voiceChannel = client.guilds.cache.get(process.env.DISCORD_GUILD_ID).channels.cache.get("539323872101531670");
let membersInChannel = voiceChannel.members.size;
const members = voiceChannel.members;
if (membersInChannel > 0) {
  members.forEach(member => {
    console.log(member.user.id);
    const randomXP = await Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    const hasLevelUP = await Levels.appendXp(member.user.id, process.env.DISCORD_GUILD_ID, randomXP)
  });
}
}, 30000);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To use `await` keyword you must work inside [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: Also, `await` isn't even needed there! However for promises, `await` or `.then` are needed. This requires an async function as described above